# How to restrict user from Exporting results of a query in SQL developer

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to create a DB read user and allow him to connect to DB via SQL Developer tool with below restrictions :

> User shouldn't be able to query data or DB structure into the box locally and 
>       upload to somewhere externally using browser

The challenge we see here is although the read only user doesn't have the ability to export the schema dump but still he can query any table and export the output of that table from SQL developer because thats is a feature of SQL developer. How can I restrict the user to even export the output of a query from SQL developer.

Comment: Your user can also run a script to get all the data in, say, CSV format or generated insert statements, and then copy that from the script output window. If they can see the data you can't really stop them using it.

Comment: May I ask why you have this requirement? Why do you allow user to select the data if you don't want him to do anything with it?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this.

Even if you prevented the ability of exporting the data, which might be possible by disabling features/extensions or removing JARs, they could still copy and paste the data out of a grid.

If you can't trust your users not to follow business rules, I wouldn't give them database accounts to begin with.

And if they abuse this, fire them. Sorry, that's not a technical answer, but I'm not sure this is really a technical question.